# How do I detect keypresses in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, keypress

How do I make VB constantly check for keypresses?
Keypresses ARE detected when debugging step-by-step, but that's it  :(
Here's my keypress code so far:

```
Private Sub Form_Main_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyPress
    'Keypress Q, A, or Z if the picture is seen for the first time
    'Otherwise one accuracy point is deducted
    If e.KeyChar = Chr(97) Then 'key a
        If PictureBox.Visible = True Then
            If MainArray(X) = 1 Then
                Timer_End = TimeOfDay.Millisecond
                PictureBox.Image.Dispose()
                PictureBox.Image = Nothing
                PictureBox.Visible = False
                Accuracy = Accuracy + 1
                CalcTime()
            Else
                Timer_End = TimeOfDay.Millisecond
                PictureBox.Image.Dispose()
                PictureBox.Image = Nothing
                PictureBox.Visible = False
                Accuracy = Accuracy - 1
                CalcTime()
            End If
        End If
    End If

    'Keypress for second occurance
    If e.KeyChar = Chr(108) Then 'key l
        If PictureBox.Visible = True Then
            If MainArray(X) = 2 Then
                Timer_End = TimeOfDay.Millisecond
                PictureBox.Image.Dispose()
                PictureBox.Image = Nothing
                PictureBox.Visible = False
                Accuracy = Accuracy + 1
                CalcTime()
            Else
                Timer_End = TimeOfDay.Millisecond
                PictureBox.Image.Dispose()
                PictureBox.Image = Nothing
                PictureBox.Visible = False
                Accuracy = Accuracy - 1
                CalcTime()
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I tried adding this to the code, but it didn't help:

```
    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Do While PictureBox.Visible = True
        Application.DoEvents()
    Loop
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Form.KeyPress should get raised each time a key is pressed.  Your eventhandler should be called regardless of if you are debugging or not.  Perhaps it is getting called, but it just isn't doing what you expect?  Try putting some debug output statments to confim the event handler is being called.

Answer (score 0):

This link might help:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.aspx#

There should also be examples of detecting certain keypresses via  KeyEventArgs Class.